# H1 title not setting correcly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set some text into h1 tag on my website (WordPress Site). I've tested my code in the footer and in the header and it is the last thing to run on the webpage before it is fully loaded.

```
<script>
function setTitle() {
    alert('ok');
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    a.innerHTML = "yourTextHere";
}

window.onload = setTitle;
</script>
```

Is anyone able to point out what is wrong with my code or is it something else conflicting with it in WordPress.

Thanks, Luke.

Comment: Set an ID on the h1 element and use document.getElementById instead that way your sure to get the right element, getElementsByTagName returns a set of elements and adding other h1 elements to you document would cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`(an array-like object).

Use

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
```

to get the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Don't use getElementsByTagName(). Instead use getElementsByID and give some ID to your h1 tag where you want to set.

And then Set it like

var a = document.getElementsByID("h1");
    a.innerHTML = "yourTextHere";
```

-

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but not really a relevant answer.